# Defining a predicate as substitute for (=)/2 (Unification) in Prolog

Tags: prolog

For my programming course's assignment, I have to write some Prolog code without using any pre-defined predicates (excluding `,` and `;`), but saw no way around using `=`, as I had to check whether a variable `A` is equal to (can be identified with) some `foo(B, C)`.

Since this isn't allowed though, I'd like to implement my own predicate `myUnification/2`, which should essentially behave in the same way, but I have no idea how to go about this. I've tried looking at the SWI-Prolog Documentation for assistance but [it only explains what the predicate does, not how it actually works internally](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=%3D/2).

Comment: Unification is baked into Prolog as an essential bit of the language. Whether you say `X = Y` or have `unify(X,X).` and evaluate `unify(X,X)`, the _*exact same thing*_ is going on under the hood_. Avoiding other built-ins, such as, say, `member/2` or `append/3` makes some sense (you can roll your own), but avoiding core primitives like `=/2`, `findall/3` (and its kin) doesn't make much sense, since it's difficult-to-impossible to implement them yourself.

Comment: I do wonder whether your programming course is teaching Prolog *badly*. How is it sensible to introduce a programming language to beginners, and then tell them that, for some unexplained reason, they cannot utilize all the available aspects of the language?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is right there in the docs :-D

```
=(Term, Term).
```

To use 'unify' instead of '=', define:

```
unify(A, A).
```

You can now do magic like this:

```
?- unify(X, foo(a, b)).
X = foo(a, b).
```

Comment: You are absolutely right, I guess I simply glossed over it and didn't realize the small box contained any meaningful information! Thanks for the quick response.